# Adding Asynchronously Generated Elements As Children To Layout

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin

I have page called **MainPage.cs**.

MainPage contains **X** amount of elements.

1/3 of **X** elements are Grids that contain information retrieved from REST API.

These Grids and information within them are absolutely necessary for the application to function.

```
class MainPage: ContentPage
{
   public MainPage()
   {
      var Scroll = new ScrollView
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children =
                {
                    // Grids that contains Y elements
                    ...
                    Some other elements X elements
                    ...
                },
            }
        };
   }
}
```

These grids are being generated within an Asynchronous methods:

```
public async Task<Grid> TopGrid(){
   var ReturnGrid = new Grid{
      RowDefinitions =
      {
         new RowDefinition {....},
      }};

   ReturnGrid.Children.Add(await GetPropertyPicker(), 0, 0);
   return ReturnGrid;
}

async Task<Picker> GetPropertyPicker()
{
   var ReturnPicker = new Picker();

   string JsonItemList = await API.GetJsonResponse(...);
   var Elements = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Property>>(JsonItemList);
   foreach (var item in Elements)
   {
       ReturnPicker.Items.Add(item.PropertyName);
   }

   return ReturnPicker;
}
```

The code above creates a gird with one row, which contains one Picker element.
Both of the methods are of type **async**.

Now the problem is that **I want to add this grid with its contents as a children to** **StackLayout**. However, it is not possible since it's not an async method and await won't work.

How would I be able or what is the advisable way of adding asynchronously generated elements to the application? Do I need to first create all the app elements "empty" and then run a async method to fill with the necessary data them?

Comment: *Do I need to first create all the app elements "empty" and then run a async method to fill with the necessary data them?* Yes that's the way to go. Also show indeterminate progress bar to let the user know you're pulling the data for user..

Comment: you can't perform async operations from the constructor, but you can make the OnAppearing method async and call them from there

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is probably to implement the mvvm pattern and set bindings to your viewmodel and let the viewmodel fill the data. But another solution i to call your async method in the OnAppearing override and then "reset" content.. like this:

```
private StackLayout layout;

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    AsyncClass.TopContent().ContinueWith((result) =>
    {         
        this.layout.Children.Add(result);
        this.Content = this.layout;
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
}
```

You have saved the stacklayout you initially set, on the layout property. If you need to get several async items in your grid i would either collect them in 1 call or just add another method too your `onAppearing()` method

Hope this helps.

Comment: `async void` would be better than `ContinueWith`.